# C Programming help needed

Tags: linker-errors

I am new to the C Programming table but i was wondering some can help me.
I am trying to build a user input program with three line but whenever I put in the information i only get zeros.
This is what I have have, can someone take a look and help me see my error please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    int plus;
    float price;
    float mealTax = (4.5/100), total = 0;
    float division;

    printf("Enter hamberger price:$ ");
    scanf("%.2f", &price);
    fflush(stdin);                     /* clear input buffer */


    mealTax = price * mealTax;
    printf("\nMeal Tax price is $%.2f * $%.2f is $%.2f\n\n", mealTax, price, division);

    total = price + mealTax;
    printf("\nTotal price is $%.2f + $%.2f = $%.2f\n\n", price, mealTax);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You've tagged this `linker-error`. Are you getting an error in the linker? If so can you post the message?

Comment: `division` variable is never initialized.

Comment: Just a quick note. You shouldn't use `fflush(stdin)`. Google it, and you will be pointed to a bunch of results saying the same thing. Basically it boils down to "fflush flushes output streams. The result of using it on input streams is undefined."

Comment: @RafaelRendonPablo not that I'm saying you shouldn't initialize your variables, but I have heard that compilers will often initialize them to 0

Comment: Your printf arguments don't match your parameters. You print "%.2f * %.2f is %.2f" and then list the arguments to print in a different/unrelated order.

Comment: @aaronman, Well, that was only an observation, not the source of the problem. :)

Comment: @RafaelRendonPablo yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scanf do not use the `.` use just `%f` the second problem is that the second `printf` is not given enough arguments to print I'm not sure what the last one you wanted to print out is but you do need one more

Comment: @ aaronman i followed your instruction and made a few changes, thank you very much but now I am having trouble with the total

Comment: I think I got it, thank you very much guys, all the points helped me see my mistakes, I really appreciate the help from everyone.

Comment: @ arronman the total is the price + meal tax you have no idea how much you helped me today because I was going insane trying to figure this out, thanks again